# When to take Epsom salt baths / use Magnesium oil?

Tags: muscle-soreness, doms

During what period of time after a training session is it optimal to take an Epsom salt bath or use magnesium oil, when you expect DOMS/muscle soreness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some scientific debate about its effectiveness but most people that use it do so after strenuous workouts where DOMS may be expected.

My preference is to deal with DOMS after lifting. After very long runs I have occasionally tried taking an ice bath and did not experience many benefits.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/121914-benefits-epsom-salt-baths/